# Having trouble making IMAP work with a catch-all email

Tags: imap, gmail-imap, catch-all

I'm having trouble making IMAP work with a catch-all email. When just attempting to sign in I get this error:

`imapclient.exceptions.LoginError: b'[AUTHENTICATIONFAILED] Invalid credentials (Failure)'`

What I've already done in attempt to fix this is: Turning on IMAP in gmail settings both in the catch all account and domain account. Turning on "Less secure access app access" on the domain account. I couldn't change it on the catch all account because it said "This setting is managed by your domain admin".

I am stuck on what else to do, I can make the bot sign in on my personal email account that isn't a catch all but can't figure out why it's not working with the catch all.

Comment: Could you share more details about what are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.